# IntelliJ IDEA - How to Align Project Pane to the left of Debug Pane

Tags: intellij-idea

Am new to IntelliJ IDEA (am using 2017.1.3)...

Was writing some sample code and didn't like how the Debug view was located as tab in the bottom right corner. Am trying to reconfigure my Intelli IDEA perspective (borrowed that term from Eclipse) so, I can have the following setup:

1. Project view as it is (completely on the left hand side like a column), on the right of that is the Debug view.
2. On the bottom of the Debug view is the Source Editor view.
3. Project view is still on the left of both the Debug and Source Editor view.

Attached is a screenshot of my plight:

[image]

As you can see, the Project view is completely under my Debug View. I want it to be completely left of both Debug and Source Editor views.

Comment: If you have two monitors - you can float the run / debug window and put it on the second screen.

Comment: So, not a duplicate then :)

Comment: Another possibility is to float the project window and put it on the screen to the left of the main window

Comment: Thanks guys, but I do not prefer floating the UI - I do have 2 screens but the other one is for IntelliJ IDEA tutorials. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Enable the **Widescreen tool window layout** option:

[image: widescreen]

See the manual: [*Optimize for wide-screen monitors*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html#wide-screen)

Comment: This worked! I really thought that IntelliJ IDEA was not able to do this! Am beginning to love this IDE!